# ibm mq keystore location over commandline

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Currently we connect to mq from our springboot application over ssl similar to [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/connect-ibm-mq-using-java-client-over-ssl-bobby-thomas). However, as you can see this is passing the keystore as a command line argument like `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password`. Is there another way to do this i.e not pass them via command-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do it from within your code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustedStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustedStorePasswd);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
```

Make sure that code is before you perform the connect call.

Note: You do not need a keystore if you are not doing mutual authentication (which most MQ applications do not do).

Comment: So if its a spring boot application, then somewhere in the Application class before run should suffice right?

Comment: @user3310115 Yes.  If you like the answer then please accept it.